# Android: Using android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Conversations

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create an app on android where I need to display messages in a chat like fashion. I've been reading on the 4.4 API for SMS and I cant seem to figure out how to use those. Currently, I am only getting the received messages from sms.Inbox Content Provider.
Can someone point me to where I can see some examples on how to make use of them efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Use `BroadcastReceiver` to get broadcast when a SMS will be received by the phone, as shown below:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

              Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
              if (extras == null)
                     return;

              // To display a Toast whenever there is an SMS.
              // Toast.makeText(context,"Recieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
              for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                     SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                     String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                     String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

                     // A custom Intent that will used as another Broadcast
                     Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra(
                                  "get_msg", sender + ":" + body);

                     // You can place your check conditions here(on the SMS or the
                     // sender)
                     // and then send another broadcast
                     context.sendBroadcast(in);

                     // This is used to abort the broadcast and can be used to silently
                     // process incoming message and prevent it from further being
                     // broadcasted. Avoid this, as this is not the way to program an
                     // app.
                     // this.abortBroadcast();
              }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I currently need is the data already stored. And not incoming messages. Though i really appreciate you posting some codes